# Methods to increase the Accuracy of the AI base Heart Sound's Classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, audio, classification

We have one GitHub Project for **classification of heart sounds** ([link](https://github.com/So-AI-love/Classification-of-Heart-Sound)), with below **README content**:

> Technology can play a role in addressing the above problem. The
> Phonocardiogram (PCG) is the method of retrieving the sound of the
> heart. This sound can capture through simple stethoscope. In this
> work, we are proposing an artificial intelligence model which have the
> potential to detect the heart abnormality from the heart sounds.
>
> The dataset can be downloaded from https://physionet.org. This data is
> also available in the link below
> https://drive.google.com/open?id=13ehWqXt8YDrmmjQc7XAUqcCk6Dwb69hy The
> data was gathered from two sources: (A) from the public via the
> iStethoscope Pro iPhone app, and (B) from a clinic trial in hospitals
> using the digital stethoscope DigiScope. There were two tasks
> associated with this data:
>
> 1. Heart Sound Feature Extraction The first task is to extract the features from the heart sounds within audio data.
> 2. Heart Sound Classification The task is to produce a method that can classify real heart sound into one of four categories (Normal, Murmur,
>    Extra-Heart Sound and Artifact).

So if possible, i asked here to find out some idea to **improve** **the validation accuracy** in
**the deep learning algorithm for classification of heart sounds** which the codes and blocks could be seen below ([link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/So-AI-love/Classification-of-Heart-Sound/blob/master/deep_pcg_3.ipynb#scrollTo=ex9lH5DX4Wot)):

[image]

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPool1D, GlobalAvgPool1D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, EarlyStopping
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.regularizers import l2

from scipy.signal import decimate

#new_labels = np.array(new_labels, dtype='int')
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
Y_test=np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=9, activation='relu', input_shape = x_train.shape[1:],kernel_regularizer = l2(0.025)))
model.add(MaxPool1D(strides=4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=(9), activation='relu',
                kernel_regularizer = l2(0.05)))
model.add(MaxPool1D(strides=4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=(9), activation='relu',
                 kernel_regularizer = l2(0.1)))
model.add(MaxPool1D(strides=4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=(9), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool1D(strides=4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=(4), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=(1), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.75))
model.add(GlobalAvgPool1D())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

def batch_generator(x_train, y_train, batch_size):
    """
    Rotates the time series randomly in time
    """
    x_batch = np.empty((batch_size, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]), dtype='float32')
    y_batch = np.empty((batch_size, y_train.shape[1]), dtype='float32')
    full_idx = range(x_train.shape[0])
    
    while True:
        batch_idx = np.random.choice(full_idx, batch_size)
        x_batch = x_train[batch_idx]
        y_batch = y_train[batch_idx]
    
        for i in range(batch_size):
            sz = np.random.randint(x_batch.shape[1])
            x_batch[i] = np.roll(x_batch[i], sz, axis = 0)
     
        yield x_batch, y_batch
        
weight_saver = ModelCheckpoint('set_a_weights.h5', monitor='val_loss', 
                               save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-4), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
annealer = LearningRateScheduler(lambda x: 1e-3 * 0.8**x)

x_train.shape

hist = model.fit_generator(batch_generator(x_train, Y_train, 8),
                   epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=1000,
                   validation_data=(x_test, Y_test),
                   callbacks=[weight_saver, annealer],
                   verbose=2)

model.load_weights('set_a_weights.h5')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Thanks.

Comment: Without know more about the data, it will be difficult to answer your question (consider providing a sample). How do you load the data? In general, please do not paste images with code - it's not helpful. Also, you might consider reviewing Stack Overflow guidelines on how to ask good questions and what to do when someone answers (you asked a lot of questions, providing thus far little feedback to people who answered).

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look to related publications. For example, work based on
[The Heat Sounds Shenzhen Corpus](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337454588_Machine_Listening_for_Heart_Status_Monitoring_Introducing_and_Benchmarking_HSS-The_Heart_Sounds_Shenzhen_Corpus) may be of use to you?

Otherwise, I agree with the above that this may not be a suitable question for stack overflow.